# Kernel dealing with the section headers in an ELF

Tags: linux, file-format, elf, kernel-mode

I recently read that the kernel and the dynamic loader mostly deal with the `program header tables` in an ELF file and that assemblers, compilers and linkers deal with the `section header tables`.

The number of program header tables and section header tables are mentioned in the ELF header in fields named  `e_phnum` and `e_shnum` respectively. `e_phnum` is two bytes in size, so if the number of program headers is > 65535, we use a scheme known as `extended numbering` where, `e_phnum` is set to 0xffff and `sh_link` field of the zeroth section header table holds the actual count.

My doubt is :

> If the count of program headers exceeds 65535, does that mean the kernel and/or the dynamic loader end up having to read the section table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked the linux kernel loading ELF function (loading_elf_binary) and I find out that if **e_phnum > (65536U / sizeof(struct elf_phdr))** or **e_phnum < 1**, the current loading routine will stop (line 613-615), the ELF file won't be loaded:

```
610         /* Now read in all of the header information */
611         if (loc->elf_ex.e_phentsize != sizeof(struct elf_phdr))
612                 goto out;
613         if (loc->elf_ex.e_phnum < 1 ||
614                 loc->elf_ex.e_phnum > 65536U / sizeof(struct elf_phdr))
615                 goto out;
616         size = loc->elf_ex.e_phnum * sizeof(struct elf_phdr);
617         retval = -ENOMEM;
618         elf_phdata = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
619         if (!elf_phdata)
620                 goto out;
```

Reference: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c

Also the number of programheader (e_phnum) in ELF32/64 is always 16 bit variable

```
203 typedef struct elf32_hdr{
204   unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];
205   Elf32_Half    e_type;
206   Elf32_Half    e_machine;
207   Elf32_Word    e_version;
208   Elf32_Addr    e_entry;  /* Entry point */
209   Elf32_Off     e_phoff;
210   Elf32_Off     e_shoff;
211   Elf32_Word    e_flags;
212   Elf32_Half    e_ehsize;
213   Elf32_Half    e_phentsize;
214   Elf32_Half    e_phnum;
215   Elf32_Half    e_shentsize;
216   Elf32_Half    e_shnum;
217   Elf32_Half    e_shstrndx;
218 } Elf32_Ehdr;
219 
220 typedef struct elf64_hdr {
221   unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];     /* ELF "magic number" */
222   Elf64_Half e_type;
223   Elf64_Half e_machine;
224   Elf64_Word e_version;
225   Elf64_Addr e_entry;           /* Entry point virtual address */
226   Elf64_Off e_phoff;            /* Program header table file offset */
227   Elf64_Off e_shoff;            /* Section header table file offset */
228   Elf64_Word e_flags;
229   Elf64_Half e_ehsize;
230   Elf64_Half e_phentsize;
231   Elf64_Half e_phnum;
232   Elf64_Half e_shentsize;
233   Elf64_Half e_shnum;
234   Elf64_Half e_shstrndx;
235 } Elf64_Ehdr;
```

Define data type as followed:

```
9 typedef __u16   Elf32_Half;
16 typedef __u16   Elf64_Half;
```

Reference: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/elf.h#L263

So, also in the case of a invalid value of e_phnum (invalid ELF file), the maximum value of e_phnum is 65535.

Hope this helpful!